# É possivel colocar os ficheiros de tradução em pastas para ficar mais organizado?

Tags: c#, globalização, asp-net-core

Eu gostava de colocar os ficheiros de traduzação organizados por pastas desta forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo o que esta na raiz da pasta **Resources** funciona mas se move para dentro dessa outra pasta deixa de funcionar como consigo configurar de modo a que consiga acessar traduções nessa pasta?

Coisas que configurei:
No ficheiro  Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(option => option.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        }
```

No inicio de cada Controller

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<ValuesController> _localizer;

public ValuesController(IStringLocalizer<ValuesController> localizer)
{
 _localizer = localizer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução então basta seguir o seguinte padrao

Se o meu controlador está na Pasta **/Controllers/NovaPasta/ExemploController.cs**

Então posso colocar o ficheiro de tradução na seguinte forma

**Resources/Controllers/NovaPasta/ExemploController.en.resx**
**Resources/Controllers/NovaPasta/ExemploController.pt.resx**

Se eu quiser reduzir uma pasta posso fazer do seguinte modo
Resources/Controllers/**NovaPasta.ExemploController.en.resx**
Resources/Controllers/**NovaPasta.ExemploController.pt.resx**

O que fiz foi adicionar o nome da pasta ao nome do ficheiro resx